# Insert arbitrary text and modify NodeArrays in the TypeScript compiler API

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

```
// Input
class Foo {
    templateString = 'some value';
}

// Output
import __LIB__ from '@scope/lib/path/to/lib';

class Foo {
    templateString = (function compiledTemplate(deps) {
        // ...
        return result;
    })({lib: __LIB__});
}
```

In fact, I have two questions:

1. How to create AST-fragment from string?
2. How to add import?

---

P.S. [I tried](https://gist.github.com/RubaXa/5896badb923f0805aa9fcdc480afe9cc) various methods `createSourceFile` and `ts.createImportDeclaration`, but they all lead to this or that error: [

Comment: Have you tried just creating an Identifier with the appropriate text for the replacement node? In other words: ``createIdentifier(`(function compiledTemplate(deps) { /*...*/ }`)``.

Comment: It's work 0_o, but how add `import lib from '@scope/lib';`?

Answer (score 5):

To add in arbitrary text, the best way I know of is to use `createIdentifier` with the string you want to insert.

---

To add in an import statement, remember that you're updating the tree *without* mutating the original.

The `ts.visitEachChild` API takes a `nodesVisitor` parameter which specially operates on `NodeArray`s. Usually, if you don't pass a `nodesVisitor` in, it will operate on each `Node` in the `NodeArray` using the first callback you pass for the `visitor` parameter, but here you specially want to operate on the full node array.

In your case, you're interested in a `SourceFile`'s statements (which is a `NodeArray<Statement>`. You can create the import with `createImportDeclaration`, and update the `SourceFile` by passing in a `nodesVisitor` like the following:

```
function addImport(statements: ts.NodeArray<ts.Statement>) {
    const importStatement = ts.createImportStatement(/*...*/);
    return ts.createNodeArray([importStatement, ...statements]);
}

visitEachChild(
    sourceFile,
    /*replace this with something that controls traversal*/ x => x,
    context, 
    addImport);
```

Comment: Alas, don't work: https://gist.github.com/RubaXa/5896badb923f0805aa9fcdc480afe9cc#file-x-danielrosenwasser-ts

Comment: Check out the example I gave for how to create a new node and how to call `visitEachChild`.

Comment: Happened, but still does not work correctly: https://github.com/RubaXa/typescript-api-questions/tree/master/import-add